# ipython equivalent for javascript/coffeescript for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipython, coffeescript

More specifically, is there a REPL that has (more) colorful output, pretty printing, tab completion and the other goodies that ipython has for node.js javascript/coffeescript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've recently started a project to provide an enhanced, extensible, embeddable interactive interpreter for multiple languages running on Node (including built-in support for CoffeeScript) here:

http://danielgtaylor.github.com/nesh/

It's pretty basic at the moment but it already provides a nice base with multi-language support and an asynchronous plugin architecture, a small set of built-in utility functions, etc. Let me know if there are any specific features you are looking for :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This project is much more mature than @Daniel claims

Comment: Nesh looks really good! I can't believe barely anybody is asking for an ipython equivalent in the node world. Ipython is so awesome.

Comment: Superb work @Daniel. Nesh is awesome.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, `node` and `coffee` are the only full-featured command-line REPLs for Node.js and CoffeeScript (respectively) right now. In their latest iterations, both offer *some* degree of colorful output, pretty printing, and completion.

Answer (score 6):

This is the best REPL available - https://github.com/princejwesley/Mancy

Answer (score 4):

Ankit, I was looking for exactly the same answer and ended up implementing it, perhaps it could be helpful for you as well: https://github.com/mksenzov/i.js

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the console in Chrome Dev Tools?
or this one: http://jsconsole.com/

Comment: I was more looking for something to run as a command-line utility for node.js (instead of running `node`, running `inode`, for example), just like `python` has `ipython`.

Comment: Though I must say, jsconsole is very cool!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for input commands history you can use this:

http://blog.doteight.com/blog/2011/01/16/rlwrap-and-node/

but this way the tab completion doesn't work...

anyone know how to call node interpreter with 
tab autocomletion turned on?